# Adding Custom Fonts in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to add custom fonts, however, the target membership is not shown to me in Xcode 12.5.1

[What should appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCi0U.jpg)
[What actually appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4s962.png)

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you added the custom font files, you must add the name list of the fonts in Info.plist file as below

[image]

Comment: I did, but that did not show the target membership. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do one thing, move your fonts right after the target I mean out side the project folder. Just try and let me know but I am not sure about it. check it here https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/8664/HVYm4E.png

Comment: Thanks for replying. Still did not work, any idea why?